# How do allow commas and space inside input type text using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on input text validation. My requirement is to allow numbers (0-9) char (a-z/A-Z) and (commas and space) only. here is what i am trying so far

`<input type="text" onkeypress="return (event.charCode === 0 )|| /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode));"/>` .

However, this code allows numbers only, how to do same for the others (chars,comma,and space).

Comment: instead of `/d/` use `/[a-zA-Z0-9 ,]/`. Or better yet, use an existing validation library.

Comment: Note that the user can edit the contents of an input element without using the keyboard...

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return (event.charCode === 0 )||  /[a-zA-Z0-9, ]/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode));"/>
```